# Android custom View: Xml vs Programmatically

Tags: android, xml, view

I am implementing custom `view` in `Android`. I was always creating it like this e.g:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.view1);
CustomView customView = new CustomView(relativeLayout.getContext());
relativeLayout.addView(customView);
```

This is working fine. But when I tried something different:

`CustomView customView = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.customView);`

in xml it's like this:

```
 <com.my.package.CustomView
       android:id="@+id/customView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I've got the error:
*android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class*

My custom view extends `RelativeLayout` and this is the only constructor:

```
public CustomView(Context c){
    super(c);
    //adding some html to the webview here
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Refer http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

Answer (score 2):

When you use your custom view from XML, the single argument constructor will not be used. Rather two/three argument constructors will be used.

You should add other constructors as well:

```
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```